# The container XXX could not be found (VSTS)

Tags: git, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I hope someone can help before I go crazy :-) until yesterday I was able to add artifacts from other VSTS projects, this suddenly stopped. Initially I thought it was an issue with my GIT repo so I tried rebuilding with no success, now I have tried setting up a test project with below settings.

VSTS test project1 -> GIT repo with a folder containing a single ps1 file (scripts\helloworld.ps1) ->

i have created a build definition (helloworld) with build step (Copy Publish artifact):

**copy root:** blank 
**contents:** scripts**
**artifact name:** helloworld
**artifact type:** server

I have within "same project" created a release definition and linked above artifact I have added following task, this runs without issues.

powershell script:
**Type:** file path
**Script path:** 
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.ps1

From another project I have created another release definition with following settings:

**Artifacts:** helloworld
**type:** build
**project:** test project1
**source (build definition):** helloworld
**source alias:** helloworld

task
powershell script:
**Type:** file path
**Script path:** 
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.ps1

But when I run this I get the following errors:
Downloading artifacts failed: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.ContainerNotFoundException: The container 1081070 could not be found.
The container 1081070 could not be found.

I am now totally lost can some help me and maybe give an answer to why this was working perfectly yesterday but not now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue if trigger the release with Hosted Build agent. I submit a feedback here: [VSTS release The container 568443 could not be found](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/33326/vsts-release-the-container-568443-could-not-be-fou.html), you can follow up it. (you submitted the issue here: [The container XXX could not be found. (hope someone can help)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3804))

The workaround is that you can setup a on premise build agent and use it for the release.

Comment: @dahund The issue will be fixed soon.